# Create python soap service from wsdl

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, marshalling

I am trying to develop a python script which would handle soap requests.  I need python objects with the right attributes, defined in the wsdl, with the data from the request to write them in the DB. How can I unmarshall the soap request with its data?

Then i have to give a response, as a soap request, defined in the same wsdl. Which library could help?

I tried suds but it doesnt allow me to unmarshall/marshall, right? Neither can it marshall a sudsobject and give me a string to add to my http response as far as i have seen. 
There isn't much documentation for that topic on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I think that suds can help you. I show you an example:

```
from suds.client import Client

# Web Service Connection
WSDL_URL_PATTERN = "http://{host}:{port}/{service_page}?WSDL"
SERVICE_PAGE = "Example.asmx"
host = host
port = port
username = username
password = password
wsdl_url = WSDL_URL_PATTERN.format(host=host, port=port, service_page=SERVICE_PAGE)
client = Client(wsdl_url, **kwargs)

#Authentication header (optional)
auth = client.factory.create('tns:AuthenticationHeader')
auth.Username = user
auth.Password = passwd
client.set_options(soapheaders=auth)

#My Function Service Call
param1 = "param1"
param2 = "param2"
result = client.service.MyFunction(param1, param2)

for item in result:
    print item.myfield
```

Comment: Suds can effectively create objects as defined in the wsdl but i wasn't able to print them in a xml format. 
And I don't really understand your "Function Service Call". What I need is to define a method for a requested SoapAction, and return the result as a SOAP request too. I just need to find a way to write the SOAP part of the http request, i can do the rest myself.